# Error with declaring scalar variable in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am working in SQL Server 2008.  I have the following stored procedure that has a dynamic SQL statement in it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.test
@list_of_codes varchar(255) = NULL,
@test_ID int = NULL
AS

DECLARE @sql1 nvarchar(max)
SELECT @sql1 =
'
INSERT INTO some_table
SELECT
some_col AS Some_Column,
@test_ID AS Testing_Identifier
FROM some_table
WHERE
testing_number_col = @test_ID
AND
test_col NOT IN (''' + REPLACE( @list_of_codes, ',', ''',''') + ''')
'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql1
'
```

I execute this stored procedure with the following statement:

```
EXEC dbo.test @list_of_codes = 'x,y,z', @test_ID = 10
```

When I execute this statement, an error is thrown, stating

```
Must declare the scalar variable ''test_ID''.
```

I'm sure my error is something as simple as escaping the @test_ID scalar variable in the dynamic SQL statement, but I don't see where I need to escape it (if that is really my problem).  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You would be far better off using a string splitter here instead of this dynamic sql approach. An even better approach would be a table valued parameter. The way you have this coded it is vulnerable to sql injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `quotes`

Considering that `@test_ID` is of `Integer` Type. If `@test_ID` is of `varchar` type then you may have to add additional quotes

```
SELECT @sql1 =
'
INSERT INTO some_table
SELECT
some_col AS Some_Column,
'+convert(varchar(20),@test_ID)+' AS Testing_Identifier
FROM some_table
WHERE
testing_number_col = '+ convert(varchar(20),@test_ID) + '
AND
test_col NOT IN (''' + REPLACE( @list_of_codes, ',', ''',''') + ''')
'
```

Comment: And again in the `where` part

Comment: Also, as `@Test_ID` is `int` you'll get an conversion failed error when you try to concat it with a string. You'll need to cast it to a `NVARCHAR`.

Comment: @Jamiec - Yeah again missed it. ty

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic part of your query knows nothing of the parameters in the outer stored procedure, so you must declare them when calling `sp_executesql`

This is covered in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx#code-snippet-2).

In your example you could use

```
DECLARE @sql1 nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @Params NVARCHAR(MAX) = '@test_ID INT'
SELECT @sql1 =
'
INSERT INTO some_table
SELECT
some_col AS Some_Column,
@test_ID AS Testing_Identifier
FROM some_table
WHERE
testing_number_col = @test_ID
AND
test_col NOT IN (''' + REPLACE( @list_of_codes, ',', ''',''') + ''')'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql1, @Params, @Test_ID=@Test_ID
```